# Login Form Using HEAD or OPTIONS Verb Instead of POST

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms, http

I have a very strange problem.  I just deployed an application to production.  I have two action methods for logging in:

```
AccountController
   [HttpGet]Login();
   [HttpPost]Login(..);
```

The form rendered to capture the login information and perform the post is a straightforward form:

```
<form action="/Account/Login" class=" form-horizontal" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="..">
.
.
</form>
```

I also log unhandled actions on the controller, which writes the message to the event log.  This is the message I see:

```
Protected Overrides Sub HandleUnknownAction(actionName As String)
    EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "Controller '" + Me.GetType().Name + "' does not have an action '" + actionName + "' for a request of type '" + Me.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod + "'.")
End Sub
```

I see this message logged:

> Controller 'AccountController' does not have an action 'Login' for a request of type 'HEAD'.
>   Controller 'AccountController' does not have an action 'Login' for a request of type 'OPTIONS'.

Any idea why the request is coming over as HEAD or OPTIONS?  I have no idea how the user is trying to connect to the application.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure you should also check user agent string logged with that request (if available) but I'd bet it's a **bot** inspecting your home page (possibly redirected to login page).

See also [googlebot head request](https://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/3929358.htm). I'd discourage user agent string filtering unless you want to keep up-to-date about this topic (and anyway a *bad* bot may fake search engine spider's user agent string).

They *usually* go with *normal* GET request but some bots (as attempt to optimize bandwidth usage?) first tries with `HEAD` and `OPTIONS`.

You have AFAIK two options: provide a specific controller method to handle them (if you care) or simply instruct bots using `robots.txt` file. Even if you leave everything as-is you shouldn't have any trouble both from security and SEO point of view (most bots will go with `GET` if receives 405 for `HEAD` and `OPTIONS`).

What's right thing to do? If you care then I'd handle them returning HTTP status 405 (*not allowed*). Someone also suggests that HTTP status 501 (*not implemented*) may be a proper/better response.

MVC *correctly* returns *Method not allowed* for unsupported `Request Method` and it also fills the (mandatory) `Allow` field in the response (in your case `Allow: GET,POST`), its behavior is equivalent to this code:

```
[ActionName("LogIn")]
[HttpOptions, HttpHead]
public ActionResult LogInForUnsupportedHttpMethods()
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);
}
```

If you're not using ASP.NET MVC 5 you don't have `HttpStatusCode` enumeration and you have to specify return code manually: `new HttpStatusCodeResult(405)`.

However not every bot/spider/service correctly switches to `GET` if `HEAD` isn't supported (notable example is [downforeveryoneorjustme.com](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/)) then you may want to return your page also for `HEAD` (and leave default behavior for `OPTIONS`):

```
// This method isn't required unless you want to return a different
// HTTP status code or to perform some special operation.
[HttpOptions, ActionName("LogIn")]
public ActionResult LogInForUnsupportedHttpMethods()
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);
}

[HttpGet, HttpHead]
public ActionResult LogIn() {/* ... */ }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(LogInModel model) {/* ... */ }
```

**Optimization**: if you're running a very high traffic web-site, you're regularly requested with **many** `HEAD` and they (in a measurable way) affect your site performance then you may decide to return a stripped down version of your page for `HEAD` requests (possibly without much server side processing and possibly unused client side stuff like CSS and scripts).